# Spring/Spring Boot conversion - how to make a chain on Converters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Please look at the example below:

```
class Foo
class Bar
class Baz

@Component
class FooToBarConverter : Converter<Foo, Bar> {
    override fun convert(source: Foo) = Bar()
}

@Component
class BarToBazConverter : Converter<Bar, Baz> {
    override fun convert(source: Bar) = Baz()
}

@RestController("/test")
class TestController(val conversionService: ConversionService) {
    @GetMapping
    fun get() = "test: " + conversionService.convert(Foo(), Baz::class.java)
    // must convert Foo to Bar, then Bar to Baz, but throws an exception instead
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: As you stated *convert Foo to Bar, then Bar to Baz* . Do that and don't try to do it in one go as that won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Not a best option. It exposes too much details to the caller, making it aware about `Bar` (which may even not be present on classpath at compile time) as well as the possibility of its conversion from `Foo` and to `Baz`. I'd like to keep such details hidden.

Comment: Then create a convert that does that. Spring won't detect you want to take 3 steps in converting from x to z. You will need to have an explicit converter for it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use
`@Autowired private List<Converter> allConverter;`

This will inject all beans that are implementing the `Converter` interface.

Now you can loop throw the list and class `convert` method.

```
allConverter.stream().forEach(Converter::convert);
```

To Manage the order of converters, you need to sort list.

Comment: Rather than iterating through all converters, you may autowire a ConversionService instance and call into it to continue the conversion.  This would probably be more performant since ConversionService caches converters for efficient lookups.  Just beware of infinite recursion if that ConversionService instance already contains this converter?